# Simple select element appcelerator

Tags: select, appcelerator, element, appcelerator-titanium

not sure if i am missing something obvious here but text fields show the keypad using Appcelerator, however there doesn't seem to be anything similar for select elements. you can use a picker but it doesn't function the same was as html select elements, ie the picker appears from the bottom and then disappears.  I am having to use [wriststrap](https://github.com/TNuzzi/wriststrap) at the moment to "fudge" this but it feels wrong.

Hopefully i am wrong and it is actually easy.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information so we can provide a better contextual answer? Are you talking about Picker controls for iOS or Android (or both)? How are you implementing the control? Some code would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android and iOS Picker Controls are quite a bit different in terms of their UI. On Android they appear very much like a standard select list in HTML. iOS pickers have the "slot machine" look to them.

Either one however can be placed at any position on the screen and do not animate from the bottom by default. If you include them within an View that animates then sure, but you can have them animate from anywhere or even just "pop" open in the center of the screen.

Looking at the picker [documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Picker), you can see how to implement one very easily. And it will look like this on the different platforms:

[image]

Android is actually a drop down (you can make it look like the spinner by using the `useSpinner="true"` property setting).

So you have full control over the style and placement of these selection tools. If your trying to maintain UI consistency between the two platforms, standardizing on a more Android like approach on iOS, that requires a custom widget which you can create or using one from the community like your doing. A good resource for alternate options is below, but Tony Nuzzi's WristStrap is pretty great :)

http://gitt.io/search?q=dropdown

Comment: Thank you, sounds like what i am doing by using WristStrap is the correct way. I just hoped it would have worked similar to text elements.

Comment: @stecooper Other then solutions like Cordove/Phonegap Appcelerator Titanium gets you a truly native UI, which also means you are "limited" to native UI components. What you ask for is not a native UI component on either Android or iOS.

Comment: Also, i'll re-iterate that because you have access to the native UI capabilities you can always create your own widget to do what you want. Sky is the limit :)